# Make USB drive with Ubuntu Linux recognized at startup or startup manager

Tags: linux, macos, usb

I have created a .dmg file and followed the instructions on the ubuntu website, but the usb drive is not on the list of items to startup or in the startup manager.  Why?  What do I need to do?

mac 10.4.11

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-an-ubuntu-installation-usb-on-the-mac/

a nice tutorial

maybe you want to install refit as well (as a bootloader)

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7926629&postcount=7 read that as well, the efi has to respond to the grub-bootloader too

Comment: thanks, I will look at this.  I just don't understand.  I followed Ubuntu's steps, why isn't the usb recognized?

Comment: Well I had the same problem once, there I made the mistake, that I forgot to convert the iso into a dmg ... and then I had the wrong bootloader...